# Google auth works only in debugging

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

i implemented Google auth with firebase. Everything is working fine if i test it directly on my Smartphone through debugging mode. if i upload a aab file to my developer console to test it in the alpha testing section, i cannot sign in with google auth. Does someone has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Check SHA-1 key, and add SHA key of system from which you have build your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add google signin SHA1 key of your app from google play store console to firebase application in firebase console.